# Creating Array Based on User input Using Scanner

Tags: java, arrays, loops, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to create a program where the user can create an array using scanner. In this example, if the first input is 4, an array with the length of 4 is then initialized. However, in the next part, the scanner is asking for 5 inputs instead of 4. If the next inputs are 1 2 3 4 5, the final output will be [2,3,4,5]. I'm not sure why it's asking for 5 inputs instead of 4. Can someone tell me what I did wrong?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        int n = s.nextInt();
        int[] numbers = new int[n];

        int input = s.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            numbers[i] = s.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("---------");

        for (int x : numbers) {
            System.out.print(x);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove the line `int input = s.nextInt();` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `int input = s.nextInt();` is consuming the first input.. that's why array is getting initialized from `2` at `0'th` index.

Remove the line `int input = s.nextInt();` and it'll work fine

Comment: oh! I didn't realize that whoops. Thanks a lot!